# TFS 2013 Rest Api - Updating Test Case results

Tags: tfs

Does anyone know what end points we can access TFS 2013 Rest API test cases?

`baseurl.com/tfs/DefaultCollection/_api` endpoints seem to work, but
`baseurl.com/tfs/DefaultCollection/{project name or id}/_api` has no endpoints that work - the documentation may be for a newer version of TFS but i'm not sure.

Any insight would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Get a test case

```
GET https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/test/plans/{plan}/suites/{suite}/testcases/{case}?api-version={version}
```

The project is an optional, with or without the project, both should be work. Not for a new version of TFS. This should work with TFS2013. Just make sure you are using the right API version=1.0. Source Link: [Test cases](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/cases)

Comment: I believe that's TFS 2015. The endpoint did not work for me. Thanks though.

Comment: I tried a bunch of different combinations... the only api endpoint that works for me is getting a list of projects. Specifically GET https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/_apis endpoint seems to work but GET https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis do not.